# When Do classes need to be allocated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, memory-management

In my program I have

```
NSString *stringOne = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World"];
[variable insertText:stringOne];
```

and the code runs fine. I know that the 'stringWithFormat:' method initiates the object, but where does the alloc happen? And why is it not needed here?

I can do the same with NSSound

```
NSSound *favoriteSong = [NSSound soundNamed:@"Friday"];
[favoriteSong play];
```

this will run, too. I know that 'soundNamed:' returns & initiates the object but the NSSound was never allocated.

I always assumed that I would have to do the following..

```
NSSound *favoriteSong = [[NSSound alloc]initWithBlablanla];
```

and then continue from there in order for everything to work.

What Im asking is, where does the allocate happen?

Comment: The system takes care of allocating `classes` -- you rarely need to worry about that.  However, `instances` are another thing entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some methods like `soundNamed` allocate an autoreleased object and return it. As an example, and let's imagine those 2 methods exist :

calling :

```
NSSound *favoriteSong = [NSSound soundNamed:@"Friday"];
```

return a NSSound allocated object, inited with @"Friday". This returned object is autoreleased.

calling :

```
NSSound *favoriteSong = [[NSSound alloc] initWithSoundNamed:@"Friday"];
```

return a NSSound allocated object, inited with @"Friday". This returned object is retained, and must be deallocated.

Those two calls would do the same thing :

```
NSSound *favoriteSong = [NSSound soundNamed:@"Friday"];
NSSound *favoriteSong = [[[NSSound alloc] initWithSoundNamed:@"Friday"] autorelease];
```

As a shortcut, soundNamed is something like :

```
+ (id) soundNamed:(NSString*)name
{
    NSSound* aSound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithSoundNamed:name];
    if (!aSound) return nil;

    return [aSound autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. Your answer was the best one out of all.. Very much appreciated brother. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

`stringWithFormat` is a connivence class method declared as:

```
+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...
```

Notice the "+" in font, that designates a class method.  The documentations states:

Returns a string created by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted.

But even this is not necessary, one can just as correctly write:

```
[variable insertText:@"Hello World"];
```

It would probably be worthwhile to read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) on Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

> When Do classes need to be allocated?

You shouldn't bother with class objects too much, it's all done automatically. I really think we're not talking about the same thing though. Maybe you mean "objects returned by class methods" instead of "classes". Something like:

**When do *objects returned by class methods* need to be allocated?**

Looks more appropriate.

> where does the alloc happen?

You answered that, right before these words. It happens inside the `+stringWithFormat:` method.

> And why is it not needed here?

It's not needed in your side, as it was already done in the library side.

> I know that 'soundNamed:' returns & initiates the object but the NSSound was never allocated.

Of course it was. If it exists, it was allocated*. Again, it was allocated inside the `+soundNamed:` method.

---

<sup>* At least in normal means. Maybe someone can cite a corner case.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Those sort of methods are called convenience (class) methods which return an autoreleased object. In other words, somewhere in the implementation for `stringWithFormat` is something similar to

```
NSString * string = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `stringWithFormat` allocates the object, puts it to  an autorelese pool and returns it to you. You can find GNUStep implementation of NSString [here](http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSString.m)